# Stop Plugin Enumeration

Tags: plugins, security, privacy

Is there any way to stop plugin enumeration? I have tried Acunetix WP Security plugin, It seems to work but Yoast SEO plugin is still enumerating. Any plugins or code modifications are appreciated.

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: What do you mean by a *plugin enumeration*? Can you give an example?

Comment: @birgire Like in http://www.wpthemedetector.com/ type any website which uses wp and it will enumerate plugins which the site is using

Comment: if a vulnerability exists in a plugin it's pointless to hide the fact that you're using that plugin, someone will just try to exploit the vulnerability, and if you have the plugin it will work, and it won't if you don't. if you look at your server logs, you'll likely see attempts to exploit things you don't have, that's typically how scripted attacks work.

Comment: I agree with @Milo here, some bots will just attack directly with some payload of known exploits and don't bother parsing your HTML source to find some plugin info.

Comment: Okay. This website is not doing anything additional that you can not find by browsing source code or in response headers. Other similar websites also take information from source code. For example if they find `wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo` path in source code then they will show you this website is using WordPress SEO plugin. Nothing special though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to stop "plugin enumeration", just use plugins from a good home and make sure you have restrictive file permission setting on your server.

In theory you can use htaccess to mask the original location of the plugin on the disk and write some code to serve any JS and CSS file as if they are located at some other directory, but this depends on the way the plugin works, some plugins might work while some might fail.

But in the end if a plugin gives admin credentials to everyone that surfs to example.com/?admin=me then the bad guys don't even need to enumerate the plugins on your site, they will just go directly to that url.